# Not overwriting wrapped text in curses

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x, curses, python-curses

I am trying to write a simple sockets-based chat application in python, and am making a client with curses.

The issue I have is that you may receive messages longer than the window width, and in this case the text wraps like expected, but the next message is written on the next line overwriting the previous one wrapped to that line.

Here is the related code:

```
def receive():
  global recv_queue
  raw_data = sock.recv(1024)
  raw_data = json.loads(raw_data)
  recv_queue.append(raw_data["TMSG"] + "\n")


def mainloop(stdscr):
  global recv_queue
  i = 1

  stdscr.clear()
  curses.cbreak()
  stdscr.keypad(1)
  stdscr.scrollok(1)
  curses.noecho()
  menu_bar = stdscr.derwin(3, curses.COLS, 0, 0)
  log_win = stdscr.derwin(curses.LINES - 6, curses.COLS, 2, 0)
  ed_win = stdscr.derwin(0, curses.COLS, curses.LINES - 4, 0)
  sub_ed_win = ed_win.derwin(2, curses.COLS - 2, 1, 1)

  box = curses.textpad.Textbox(sub_ed_win, insert_mode=True)
  while True:

    log_win.border()
    ed_win.border()
    menu_bar.box()

    menu_bar.refresh()
    log_win.refresh()
    ed_win.refresh()
    sub_ed_win.refresh()

    t = threading.Thread()
    t.run = box.edit
    t.start()

    receive()

    try:
      log_win.addstr(i, 1, recv_queue.pop().encode("utf_8"))
      i += 1
    except:
      pass


wrapper(mainloop)
```

The part where I start a thread for editing `box` can be ignored, it isn't finished yet.

Comment: The thread can interfere with updates to box.edit, since curses isn't threadsafe.

Comment: I am aware of that. That is why I said it can be ignored.